# How to add a Pdfptable little by little to a document when generating a Pdf from a Html

Tags: c#, html, itext, xmlworker, pdfptable

The application I'm working on generates pdf reports from html files using itextsharp library. Apparently, when large tables are generated, itextsharp allocates a lot of memory (~300 MB for a 200KB file). 
A solution to this problem is adding the table little by little to the document (so all existing data in table will be flushed), as described in the following links:

- [IText Large Tables](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/large-tables)
- [How to reduce memory consumption of PdfPTable with many cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482142/how-to-reduce-memory-consumption-of-pdfptable-with-many-cells)

**Question**: How can I add a pdfptable in steps when generating the pdf from an existing html file?

Here is my code:

```
public byte[] GetReportPdf(string template, string cssString)
    {
        byte[] result;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (
                var doc = new Document(
                    this.Settings.Size,
                    this.Settings.Margins.Left,
                    this.Settings.Margins.Right,
                    this.Settings.Margins.Top,
                    this.Settings.Margins.Bottom))
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream))
                {
                    // adding the page event, or null
                    writer.PageEvent = this.Settings.PageEvent;

                    doc.Open();

                    // CSS
                    var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();

                    using (var cssStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssString)))
                    {
                        var cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(cssStream);
                        cssResolver.AddCss(cssFile);
                    }

                    // HTML
                    var fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
                    var cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
                    var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
                    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                    // pipelines
                    var pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer);
                    var html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
                    var css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

                    // XML worker
                    var worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
                    var parser = new XMLParser(worker);
                    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(template))
                    {
                        parser.Parse(stringReader);
                    }


                    doc.Close();
                }
            }

            result = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
```

**Notes**:

1. The solution in the previous links are not using an html to create
   the pdf
2. The steps described are: set table complete property to false, add every 50 table rows to the document, set the table complete property to true.
3. Using an AbstractTagProcessor, I managed to set the table complete property when the html is parsed, **but found no option on how to trigger table adding while it's generated.**
4. itextsharp version 5.5.10.0
5. itextsharp.xmlworker version 5.5.10.0

var tagFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();

```
tagFactory.AddProcessor(new TableTagProcessor(doc), new string[]{"table"});

public class TableTagProcessor : iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.table.Table{

public override IList<IElement> Start(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag)

{
    var result = base.Start(ctx, tag);
    foreach (PdfPTable table in result.OfType<PdfPTable>())
    {
        table.Complete = false;
    }

    return result;
}

public override IList<IElement> End(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList<IElement> currentContent)
{
    var result = base.End(ctx, tag, currentContent);
    foreach (PdfPTable table in result.OfType<PdfPTable>())
    {
        table.Complete = true;
    }

    return result;
}}
```